# Range not working in Golang, as a return value

Tags: go

I want to range over an array in golang and I want to return the resulting data as a value and print it out in the main function using the fmt.Println(funcName).
But it only seems to be getting the first value in the array and not really iterating through it all.
The code is below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var cube [2][4]int

func test1(num int) {
    for _, loop := range cube[num] { //0-3
        fmt.Println("test one returns ", loop)
    }
}

func test2(num int) (res int) {
    for _, loop := range cube[num] { //0-3
        res = loop
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    test1(1) //range over the second column
    fmt.Println("ISSUE BELOW!")
    fmt.Println("test two returns: ", test2(0)) //range over the first column, result should look like that of the upper function.
}
```

Try it out here:
https://go.dev/play/p/L8U5t5Yq80W

Probably it's that the iteration isn't possible on a return value?, maybe return values are only updated once?

Comment: Thanks, I've already done that! The other way.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `test1` and `test2` is that `test1` is looping over the values and printing each out, while `test2` is looping over them and setting `res` to each as it iterates.  When the function returns, the variable will only contain the last value to which it was set.

Something to note is that the returned variable doesn't become a stream, channel, or generator type because it is declared with the function.  Setting it equal to different values over the course of the function does not result in multiple values being returned from the function.  Specifying a return variable name is mostly a shorthand to say which variable should be returned (ie. the `return` is really `return res`).  It's still the type specified (in this case `int`).

To get something more similar to what you may want, you could return an int slice and `.append()` values into it.  You will still need to iterate over the slice to print the values, though, so it won't help much for this specific case.

Comment: Woah, I guess that's gonna be a dead end then, thank you very much though!, for the efforts.

Comment: What if I return a channel instead of an int?, it should probably be a better work around right?.

Comment: Channels could be good for that, depending on your ultimate use case.  It'd involve using multiple Go routines for channels to make sense.  They'd be more ideal if there's going to be some concurrency related to the output of the function.  Otherwise a simple slice would generally be better.  The usage for each would generally be the same (i.e. range-ing over the result).

Comment: okay i will try using the channels first and i may try the slice if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`test2` is also looping over indexes `0` to `3` you just don't see the evidences. If you write a `fmt.Println` inside you will get the same result as in `test1`:

```
func test2(num int) (res int) {
    for _, loop := range cube[num] { //0-3
        fmt.Println(loop)
        res = loop
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that, but I don't want to use the fmt.Println function, I want to return  the iterated value in full.

Comment: My idea was to prove that `test1` and `test2` loop over the "second column". Whether you need it in your example  is not relevant. Can you try and explain how the end result should look like? And what specifically is causing your surprise?

Comment: yes, thanks again, im trying to achieve a looped rerturn value just like test1, my reason for wanting a return value instead of a print is cause i want to use the end program as a module for my main project,  i guess i will be using a channel and a goroutine. internal function, still im open for more suggestion from you though.